# Get records on the base of one field which should distinct

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

i have query like

```
    SELECT distinct(a.CreatedOn),
       a.id AS ID ,
       u1.FirstName CreatedByFirstName,
       u1.LastName
FROM AuditDetail a
LEFT JOIN UserProfile u1 ON a.CreatedBy = u1.UserProfileID
LEFT JOIN UserProfile u2 ON a.UpdatedBy = u2.UserProfileID
```

this shows me all the records. and distinct createdon also repeated in each records because all the records comming. i want that if the createdon is same in all the records then its first record or single record should come not all. where i'm wrong?

[image]

Comment: can you provide the sample results you've got from this statement?

Comment: checkout the daigram! the results same like the above picture shows... @wy__

Comment: the 'ID' is different, it supposed to return duplicate createdon. if you want a single createdon record you should get rid of a.id selection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ranking Function` such as `ROW_NUMBER()` which give rank on each record for every group.

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
    SELECT  a.CreatedOn,
            a.id as ID ,
            u1.FirstName CreatedByFirstName, 
            u1.LastName,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.CreatedOn ORDER BY a.CreatedOn) rn
    FROM    AuditDetail a 
            left join UserProfile u1 
                on a.CreatedBy = u1.UserProfileID 
            left join UserProfile u2 
                on a.UpdatedBy = u2.UserProfileID
)
SELECT  CreatedOn,
        ID,
        CreatedByFirstName,
        LastName
FROM    recordList
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

Might will help you, used subquery

```
SELECT a.CreatedOn,
       a.id AS ID ,
       u1.FirstName CreatedByFirstName,
       u1.LastName
FROM AuditDetail a
LEFT JOIN UserProfile u1 ON a.CreatedBy = u1.UserProfileID LEFT joinUserProfileu2 ON a.UpdatedBy = u2.UserProfileID
WHERE a.CreatedOn IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT CreatedOn
     FROM AuditDetail)
```